# Deleting old Dropbox files?

Tags: filesystems, dropbox, uninstall

I installed Dropbox, and after some time I uninstalled it. Now i see stuff from Dropbox in my user folder. It wasn't created on this machine, but they were copied here. If i delete them, do they get deleted from Dropbox too?

Answer (score 1):

**(A)** If you still have your Drop Box Account, and you delete the files locally, then YES, deleting the local files will delete from Drop Box.

You should temporarily install Drop Box and log in to ensure this happens.

**(B)** If you do not log into Drop Box, then NO, deleting local files will not delete the Drop Box files.

In this case you can also log into Dropbox.com and delete files that way.

**(C)** If you deleted your Drop Box Account, then the file are gone in any event.

Comment: I haven't deleted my account, and those files were not made on this PC. I uninstalled Dropbox and this computer doesn't contain anything that has something to do with it. But I think that if I get rid of these, they won't affect that Dropbox account.

Comment: Then use (B) log in to Drop Box and delete file from there if there are any, otherwise no issue with Drop Box files.